# Create ObjectInputStream according to a socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to create an ObjectInputStream according to a Socket and add this stream into a List.
The client is connected in the main class of my program, and the socket is sent in an other method in a Thread. Then the socket is used to create the stream.
The problem is that the stream is never create. I don't get why...

Below is my code :

In my Thread :

```
public void addClient(Socket socket){
    try{
        streamList.add(new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And in my main class :

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
Socket socket;
ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread();
//start the thread

try{
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
    clientThread.addClient(socket);
}
catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The peer needs to create his `ObjectOutputStream` immediately on connection. Otherwise `new ObjectInputStream` will block until he does so.

It would be better if you could defer creation of the `ObjectInputStream` to the `run()` method of the thread that handles the accepted socket. You shouldn't do any I/O in the accept loop, just the accept itself. Otherwise you can block subsequent clients.